# cakephp 2 apps same file name issue

Tags: cakephp

I have 2 apps sharing the same cake core. Both apps contains similar file names for controllers and models. If debug is ON (> 0), both applications are working without any error. If it is off, whichever app I taken first in the url will work and other will show error like the **method not found** in the logs. I know, this is something related to cache.
Both apps have different tmp folder and I have given necessary permission. But the second app is taking looking into the tmp of first one so that app2 methods will not be there in that tmp. I checked by deleting the cache files and sometimes they are not regenerating. How to solve this issue ?
My folder structure

project folder

app1

- Controller
- Model
- tmp

  etc
  app2

  - Controller
- Model
- tmp
  etc
  lib
- cake

Comment: I have 10+ sites running on the same Cake lib and I've never seen this... so I have to assume it's something with your structure, but can't see any issue with what you've provided... can you share you're three altered webroot/index.php lines?  That's the only thing I can think for now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a cache issue. You most likely are using APC and did not specify unique prefix for cache config for each app. Be sure to change the default `$prefix = "myapp_"'` line in `app/Config/core.php` to unique values for each app.